# Synonym requests for [php-gd]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

The [PHP interface to the GD image processing library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) is widely used and contains a number of functions that have somehow taken on a life of their own as tags. I don't see the value in having separate tags for separate functions.

In my opinion, these tags should all be made synonyms of [php-gd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-gd):

- [php-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-image) (this tag had a couple dozen questions I changed to [php-gd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-gd) manually)
- [createimagefrompng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/createimagefrompng) (manually changed about 60 questions to [php-gd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-gd))
- [php-imagecopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-imagecopy) (15 questions manually changed to [php-gd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-gd))
- [getimagesize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getimagesize) (170 questions)
- [imagettftext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imagettftext) (150 questions)
- [gdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gdlib) (138 questions)